# Can I use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore in a standard .NetFramework solution in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019

Does Microsoft EntityFrameworkCore work with standard .Net Framework applications?
I read a couple posts which said it was possible to.
However, when attempting to install via NuGet Package Manager, I get the following error message:

> Could not install package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
> 5.0.0". You are trying to install this package into a project that targets ".NetFramework, Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not
> contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible
> with that framework.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is EntityFrameworkCore not intended for use with standard .NetFramework applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I have to correct my answer, I was wrong. EF Core 3.1 can be used with .NET Framework 4.7.2 or later.

Comment: OK. It looks like I'll create a .NetCore WebAPI to wrap it and use it there. Thx

Comment: Wrong, you can use EF Core 3.1 with .NET Framework 4.7.2 or later

Answer (score 0):

EF Core 5.0 cannot be used with .NET Framework 4.7.2 
see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/ef/core/miscellaneous/platforms
*I also tried it before and got the same error message described above*